# Page document view/zoom c#

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to c#, I've created a MdiContainer that contains some form (a very simple text editor).

Now I'm trying to have a zoom function like in msword (image below) that allow the user to view "the borders" of the document.
What kind of control should I use or focus on? Is there any example? I would like to avoid external library cause this is a learning project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explore System.Drawing.Printing namespace then. There are classes like  PrintDocument, PrintDialog and PrintPreviewControl. These controls are complex in nature. You can view the page settings or adjust border settings using these controls.